# Is there a code to save the output of the onclick box of this example in a txt file?

Tags: html, geolocation

I am using this code for  my website, it works prefect but I need to save the output of every 
single click on a Txt file, any ideas ?

Tried to find some sort of code, but was only able to find php codes

```js
 
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
```

```html
    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

I am expecting the same results, plus a text file that includes every single click result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) will allow you to save data to the filesystem. Here is a minimally functional use of the method:

```
function download(text, name, type) {
  let a, file
  file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
  a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = name;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}
download('foo bar', 'sample.txt','text/json');
```

If you want to save all clicks to a single file, you'll need to accumulate them within a data structure of choice before passing the data off to the download function.